# Adding float to some divs, moves page over a few pixels

Tags: html, css

I have a web design class project. I'm creating mine about a computer shop I came up with. But I'm having a couple issues. I've attached my code to show you why.  So I have a couple DIVs with the float tag and on certain pages it moves the entire page over a couple pixels. How can I fix that? Also I want all my pages to be centered and at the same position horizontally, whenever I switch over to my homepage from my news page for example, the home page is moved like ten pixels to the left when it shouldn't be. It didn't do this until I added my featured product with the float style.  Here's my code:

index.html (this page is moved over a few pixels)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Terry's Computers</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="script/scripts.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="images/banner.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="news.html">News</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Parts 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="cases.html">Cases</a>
                        <a href="motherboards.html">Motherboards</a>
                        <a href="processors.html">Processors</a>
                        <a href="graphics.html">Graphics Cards</a>
                        <a href="storage.html">Storage</a>
                        <a href="powersupplies.html">Power Supplies</a>
                        <a href="ram.html">RAM</a>
                        <a href="other.html">Other</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Builds 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="contact" id="navright">
                    <a href="contact.html" style="float:right;">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="featured">
            <div id="l_product" style="background-color:white;">
                <img src="images/featured.gif" class="featured_image">
            </div>
            <div id="r_product">
                <p class="featured_text_title">ASUS Prime Z370-A</p>
                <ul class="featured_text">
                    <li>the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet</li>  
                    <li>the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet</li>  
                    <li>the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet</li>  
                    <li>the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet</li>  
                    <li>the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet is the big yeet</li>  
                </ul>
                <img src="images/buy_button.png" class="buy_button">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="first">
            <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
            <p class="paragraph">
                Here at Terry's Computers we are determined to make our customers experience as 
                stress free as possible.  We will help every customer find the best deal possible
                for their budget.  Here we have computer parts such as motherboards, processors, and
                more to offer.  We also offer prebuilt computers that range from productivity, gaming,
                or whatever the customer desires.  We also take custom requests that can more suit our customers.  
                We can help you find the perfect computer that will satisfy your needs.  If you have any
                questions or suggestions head over to the <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> page and send us an email.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footertext">
                <p>Here at Terry's Computers we do not claim to own any of 
                    the products shown on this website.</p>
                <a href="contact.html"><p>Contact Us</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a normal page:

news.html (page is right where it should be)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Terry's Computers - News</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="script/scripts.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="images/banner.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="news.html">News</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Parts 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="cases.html">Cases</a>
                        <a href="motherboards.html">Motherboards</a>
                        <a href="processors.html">Processors</a>
                        <a href="graphics.html">Graphics Cards</a>
                        <a href="storage.html">Storage</a>
                        <a href="powersupplies.html">Power Supplies</a>
                        <a href="ram.html">RAM</a>
                        <a href="other.html">Other</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Builds 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="contact" id="navright">
                    <a href="contact.html" style="float:right;">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsfooter">
            <div class="footertext">
                <p>Here at Terry's Computers we do not claim to own any of 
                    the products shown on this website.</p>
                <a href="contact.html"><p>Contact Us</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my stylesheet:

stylesheet.css

```
body{
    background-color: #201f38;
    margin: 0;
}
.page{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
.banner{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
.navigation{
    width: 960px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #23004E;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #23004E;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.active{
    background-color: #400089;
}
.first{
    background-color: #6C01E5;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.title{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40pt;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.featured{
    width: 960px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #6C01E5;
    margin: 15px auto;
    height: 494px;
    padding: 18px;
}
.featured_image{
    padding: 22px;
}
#l_product{
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.featured_text_title{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
.featured_text{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 61px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: justify;
}
.buy_button{
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 97px;
}
#r_product{
    float: right;
    width: 450px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #7143a5;
}
.suggestion_box{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #1e2994;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 15px auto;
    height: 492px;
    padding: 18px;
}
.paragraph{
    text-indent: 50pt;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
#container{
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 125px;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    margin: 15px auto;
    margin-bottom: -33px;
    height: 100%;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
    width: 226px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
    background: #7143a5;
}
.box_image{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.box_header{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.box_text{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin: 0px;
}
.square_box2{
    width: 471px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    background-color: #7143a5;
}
.box2_image{
    width: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.box2_text{
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 50px;
    width: 241px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
.newsfooter{
    width: 960px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
.footer{
    width: 960px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: auto;
}
.footertext{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
.footertext a{
    font-size: 7pt; 
}
#ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    z-index: 1001;
}
#popup{
    width: 450px;
    height: 375px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    background: #7143a5;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.close{
    width: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 410px;
}
#contact_page{
    width: 960px;
    padding: 18px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #1e2994;
    margin: 15px auto;
    height: 492px;
}
.contact_header{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    text-align: center;
}
.contact_form{
    width: 450px;
    background-color: #7143a5;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 15px 122px;
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.contact_info{
    width: 450px;
    background-color: #7143a5;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#map{
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.address{
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
input{
    width: 200px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    border: 3px solid black;
    outline: none;
    text-indent: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type="text"]{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
label{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
textarea{
    width: 200px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    border: 3px solid black;
    outline: none;
    text-indent: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 90px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 90px;
}
.contacttext{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.submit{
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add parent (.container) class and set width to that parent no need to set width for every block.

```
.container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="banner"></div>
   <div class="navigation"></div>
   <div class="featured"></div>
   <div class="first"></div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```